# How to deploy Moquette broker in Android?

Tags: java, android, mqtt, mosquitto, moquette

Can we deploy a Moquette/Mosquitto broker inside Android for MQTT client communication?

I want to deploy a Moquette/Mosquitto broker inside Android and one MQTT client will communicate to another using that broker.

Comment: For what purpose do you want to run the broker inside an Android application rather then on a server?

Comment: Actually you are right I must deploy the broker in server but....once I deploy broker inside the server than my application will IPC specific (that means I have to use the internal API for internal communication) but I wanna make my application protocol specific .

Comment: Is it possible if yes than how ?

Comment: Any luck with running a broker on Android? Very interested I am.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretical speaking, yes you can because [Moquette](https://github.com/andsel/moquette) is a java based broker, and Android uses java SDK, but practically, that should not ever be made.

You would need a mqtt client, which in your case, a Java client, such as [paho](https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/java/) client, and the broker should be running on a real server

Comment: yes that can embedded as either activity or service

Answer (score 1):

There must exist a major reason to have a Broker embedded in a mobile client an not in a server.

The rationale is that you have the broker running in a server, then several mobile clients exchange messages by publishing and subscribing to specific topics in the server broker.

For that reason mobile clients should implement MQTT clients such as Paho Android Service:
https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/android/

Comment: Actually Broker is running in Server side.but if I embedded one broker in Android device so all the communication over MQTT which will save my maintenance effort.

Comment: Mobile MQTT Client (Paho) <-----> Server MQTT Broker (Moquette)

If you have an MQTT client in your mobile app, all communication will be over MQTT protocol and you can publish (send) or subscribe (receive).

Comment: Yes I am following same approach, actually internal & as well as external communication over MQTT . if I go with this approach I can reuse most of the code for both internal & external communication

Comment: You can try if it make sense to a) The rationale of porting effort and device resource consuming to make Moquette running as an Android Background Service in order to assure that is running all the time (even if you close the app). b) Only run the Moquette when the app is running (for inter-app communications) and for the Mobile to Server communication use the Paho Android Service MQTT Client.